# Come tradurreste l'espressione "leakage bandwidth"?

Tags: translation, mathematics

Mi sono imbattuto recentemente in [questo](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-69053-0_6.pdf) articolo matematico. A pagina 5 del file si legge la seguente parte.

[image]

Provo a spiegare brevemente questo articolo. Supponete di avere un dispositivo (per esempio il vostro smartphone) utilizzato per comunicare con sicurezza con un vostro amico, in sostanza, vengono cifrati i messaggi  (per esempio su WhatsApp si legge spesso "crittografia end-to-end"). Supponete che il vostro dispositivo sia stato manomesso in modo tale che un malintenzionato, recuperando *n* messaggi cifrati da voi inviati (ricordiamo che i messaggi sono stati cifrati), ne riesca a decifrare (e quindi effettvamente a leggere) *m* di questi. In generale, con *n* utilizzi del dispositivo riesco a far trapelare (*leak*) *m* informazioni. Gli autori si sono chiesti "Come possiamo misurare la *leakage bandwidth* di questa manomissione?" Risposta: "Questo è un *(m,n)-leakage scheme*".

A questo punto mi sono chiesto "Come si potrebbero tradurre in italiano le espressioni *leakage bandwidth* e *(m,n)-leakage scheme* in modo da avere un tono accattivante e non pesante?

Per *leakage bandwidth* ("bandwidth" non ha relazioni con le frequenze) non saprei che traduzione esprimere. Io avevo pensato a "misura/grandezza/capacità di dispersione" ma ho paura che "dispersione" sia un po' fuori contesto tenendo conto dell'analisi che riporto più sotto circa la parola "leak".   Mentre  *(m,n)-leakage scheme* la tradurrei come "schema (m,n) di filtraggio" o "schema (m,n) di dispersione", proprio perché, in questo contesto leggo "leak" come "impadronirsi, rubare, far trapelare, appropriarsi"; una sorta di fuga di notizie.

Voi avete qualche consiglio migliore di traduzione?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi lancio in una proposta “indecente”:

- leakage bandwidth → [trapelamento](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trapelamento/) (senza ampiezza di banda né altro – al limite “entità del trapelamento”)
- leakage scheme → schema di trapelamento

Forse aggiungerei anche l'originale inglese tra parentesi.

La traduzione verrebbe più o meno così:

> **2.3 Trapelamento (leakage bandwidth)**
>
> Definiamo ora il trapelamento (leakage bandwidth) nei crittosistemi.
> Si riferisce a ciò che può trapelare da crittosistemi (p. es.
> generazione di chiavi, o scambio di chiavi) che sono invocati
> ripetutamente.
>
> **Definizione 4.** Uno schema di trapelamento (*m*,*n*) è un meccanismo
> SETUP che fa trapelare *m* chiavi o messaggi segreti su *n* messaggi
> prodotti dal dispositivo crittografico (*m* ≤ *n*).
>
> L'attacco al logaritmo discreto che presentiamo è uno schema di trapelamento
> (1,2) in cui con due generazioni di chiave siamo in grado di far
> trapelare una chiave all'attaccante. Mostriamo come questo schema può
> essere esteso per diventare uno schema di trapelamento (*m*,*m*+1).

Answer (score 3):

Prima di tutto, non vedo perché non tradurlo, o almeno provarci. Come opinione personale, mi dispiace che nemmeno si provi a tenere l'italiano, almeno in parte, aggiornato anche come lingua scientifica.

Entrando nel merito, *bandwdith*, da solo, si tradurrebbe in modo abbastanza pacifico come “larghezza (o ampiezza) di banda”. Ma qui c'entrano veramente delle frequenze o è un uso figurato? Nel secondo caso potremmo mantenere semplicemente “larghezza”, “ampiezza”, “estensione” o simili.

*Leakage* è il più rognoso. Se tu conosci bene il senso dell'articolo potrai trovare di meglio (e già proponi “filtraggio” e “dispersione”), ma io ci vedo più un senso quasi di “perdita” o “fuga” (come per il gas); l'uso tipico è quello relativo a un tubo o un contenitore che non tiene bene. Se vogliamo essere ricercati, addirittura “colaggio” o “sfrido”.

Quindi basta assemblare due di questi termini: “ampiezza della perdita/del colaggio”? Non so, farei un po' di prove e vedrei che cosa funziona meglio nel contesto.

Infine, occhio che *scheme* non corrisponde sempre del tutto all'italiano “schema”. Il termine italiano indica un modello, una struttura, un diagramma, mentre quello inglese si avvicina spesso al senso di “metodo”, “procedimento”, “piano” (per fare qualcosa) e addirittura a “trucco” o “intrigo” (anche se questi ultimi non c'entrano qui). Si parla di uno *scheme* per ridurre la disoccupazione o per truffare gli ingenui (come il *Ponzi scheme*). Quindi qui potrebbe essere – ma ancora una volta, sai meglio tu di che cosa si parla – di un “metodo (*m*, *n*) di perdita/colaggio/dispersione...”.

Comment: Grazie mille per la risposta, adesso modifico il post originale in modo da rendere più chiaro il significato di queste espressioni. Rispondo già per *scheme*: credo sia corretto tradurre con "schema" o al massimo "meccanismo" perché proprio di meccanismi si parla.

Comment: Comunque mi trovi d'accordo con te riguardo il pensiero iniziale che hai espresso. Proprio per questo motivo ho chiesto consiglio in questo forum(?).

Comment: leakage = fuoriuscita?

Comment: Anche si, ma è una parola pesante è un po' decontestualizzata. A mio avviso suona male "schema (m,n) di fuoriuscita".

Comment: Con un neologismo, tradurrei "leakage" con "rubaggio" (per esempio). Il rubare insomma. Sarabbe carino trovare un parola il cui significato sia "il rubare/rubaggio" ma che non sia cacofonica. Non so se mi sono spiegato.

Comment: Il senso di "leakage bandwidth" dovrebbe essere "quantità dell'informazione rubata/fatta trapelare", solo detto in modo più conciso e foneticamente gustoso.

Answer (score 2):

Tradurre in italiano certe espressioni tecniche implica che il lettore perderà i riferimenti quando andrà a leggere altra documentazione che sarà quasi esclusivamente inlingua inglese, quindi il mio consiglio è non tradurre o almeno lasciare il riferimento all'originale inglese.
In informatica la maggior parte della letteratura traduce:

- Leakage come perdita.
- Bandwidth come banda o ampiezza del canale. In questo caso userei ampiezza.
  Ampiezza della perdita rende bene l'idea e non è pesante
  Schema è strano e mi dà l'idea che l'autore non fosse madrelingua inglese. Non è un termine molto usato in informatica. Forse configurazione potrebbe essere il termine giusto in questo caso

Comment: Certe espressioni tecniche perdono solo significato nel tentativo di tradurle. Non si deve fare mai.

Answer (score 1):

Leak/leakage normalmente definisce una perdita, per es. d'acqua in un impianto idraulico. Figurativamente è poi passata a descrivere altri tipi di perdite dovute a falle in altri sistemi, per es. una fuga di notizie (poi ripreso per es. in WikiLeaks).
Se mi dovessi lanciare in una traduzione di leakage in questo contesto, spillatura/spillaggio d'informazione mi pare possa rendere l'idea di qualcosa che è intenzionalmente sottratto da una parte più grande o come prodotto o come scarto.
Bandwidth in questo contesto mi pare si possa riferire ad un calcolo il cui risultato descrive lo spettro nel quale il furto d'informazione è possibile.
Mettendo insieme le due parti: (calcolo dello) spettro di spillaggio dell'informazione.
Non so quanto posso apparire appropriato.

Answer (score 1):

Trafilaggio potrebbe andare?

Non riguarda la trafilatura ed è un sinonimo di perdita; l'ho sempre sentito usare in meccanica per indicare perdite di olio o liquido in generale, solitamente causate da errato serraggio o non perfetta aderenza tra due superfici (trafilaggio di olio dalla testata/dalla coppa).

In caso di crittografia non ci sono superfici, ma stiamo parlando di dati che 'scivolano fuori' tra le maglie di un algoritmo che non dovrebbe avere 'fessure'.

Mi sento però di concordare con l'osservazione relativa al contesto: in ambito informatico italianizzare un termine del genere rischia di rendere il testo meno comprensibile a chi nel settore ci lavora.